# I have table of 56 columns and want to load 46 columns of data how can I do it?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a table containing 56 columns (main table) and I want to load data into it from the different table which contains 46 columns. I tried exporting 46 columns data into CSV and tried loading data into the main table .it got loaded but data was a mismatch. Can anyone please help me on this...e.g.
 Empid contains data of emp name.

load data local inpath '/home/data/download/sample.csv' into table slave_table
Select * from slave_table

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

1.Create a table that holds the 46 cols from csv:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE TABLENAME                                                 
(COLS)                                               
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'                                                       
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("separatorChar"=",", "quoteChar" = '~', "escapeChar" = "Δ", "skip.header.line.count"="1")    
STORED AS TEXTFILE
```

**Please modify the serdeproperties with what you need!**

2.Insert from this new created table into your 56 cols table with an insert like this:

```
Insert into TABLE_WITH_56_COLS (name the 46 cols that you want to populate)
select 46 cols from TABLE_WITH_46_COLS;
```

Hope that this helped you!